# Animated gif's speed is very slow

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

I have an animated gif that is 4kb in size that I am using for a simple javascript app. It is ten frames with each framed at 0.01 seconds. I export it in photoshop and the preview looks as it should. When I preview my app in Chrome & Firefox the animation plays as though it were playing at 0.1 seconds a frame. You can see the image below. It should be going much quicker. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Lol, that's awesome! I tried, Now it's too quick ;)

Comment: Googling around it looks like 10fps might be the minimum for some browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That gif may actually be set to 0 fps due to the tiny FPS you set it to, or buggy creation software.

IE automatically puts a delay of around 40 ms between frames if this is the case.

I would try different creation software, OR I would lower the framerate to around 40ish and see if it starts to sync up in all browsers.  That should give you your answer.

Answer (score 3):

try 0.05 seconds, it is correct "No delay"

Comment: Thank you! This makes it the right speed. "No delay" seems to make things slower but everyone says to use that as the setting.

Comment: Thanks - this is the real answer. I changed my frames from "no delay" to to 0.02 and it works great now 

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be moving along at a pretty good pace for me. You may want to preload the image before rendering it. This will eliminate the delay that comes with the initial load.

Comment: It look fine but it's actually supposed to be rendering 10 times as fast. It's going 10 fps when it needs to go 100fps. Preview in photoshop looks fine but browser no

Comment: Ah. I see. As mentioned previously, I think you have run into a tehnological limitation of the browser.

Comment: I think you're right. As I do more research it looks like browsers only support up to 10fps.